# Android Studio Benefits vs Eclipse with ADT

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have looked in different places, but I am not REALLY sure as to what to use. I'll explain:

I'm self-teaching myself, with various books and tutorials. I use Eclipse with the ADT, but it seems now that Google is really pushing people to use AStudio (especially after its recent stable release). I have heard that AStudio has the following benefits:

---

- Gradle Build
- Improved Visual Editor
- Improved code completion

Amongst many other benefits...

For starters, what are the benefits of AStudio put simply? (For example, what actually IS Gradle building?!)

However, for a novice like myself, would it be beneficial for me to switch to AStudio? (considering that I'm also trying to teach myself some CORE Java)

Sorry if this seems like a repetition, but I was just hoping to recieve information in terminology that I can *understand*...

Thanks!

Comment: Since Eclipse is no longer supported by Google, I would not recommend that a newcomer use Eclipse at the present time. "what actually IS Gradle building?" -- your app.

Comment: @CommonsWare Okay. What do you mean "your app"?

Comment: "For starters, what are the benefits of AStudio put simply?", its an official Android IDE and will receive all sort of updates frequently as compared to Eclipse, which will soon be obsoleted..

Comment: By "your app", I mean "the app that you, as a developer, are writing".

Comment: @CommonsWare I appreciate your effort, but I would benefit more from answers WITH substance.

Comment: @MrChasi the literal APK file, which is a product of compiling the code that you, as a developer, have written, is produced by the Gradle build process. But IANAL

Comment: This question is too much opinion-based, but as a reference take a look at the new Eclipse project Andmore, which will continue development of the Android tools on Eclipse: https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.andmore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio is the new IDE for developing Android apps. Google decided to change it, and so we must follow. I found an article that compares Eclipse and Studio for you: http://news.dice.com/2014/03/19/googles-android-studio-vs-eclipse-fits-needs/

You want to know what Gradle is?
Gradle can automate the building, testing, publishing, deployment and more of software packages or other types of projects such as generated static websites, generated documentation or anything else.
For example, it is possible to simply add a Sonar connection, to check your code.
Also Gradle uses dependency management, which will make it a lot easier to add libraries to your projects, and sharing them with other developers. 
Where Eclipse required to have a local copy of a library downloaded on your pc, gradle automates this. Add the library to your graddle file, and it will download the package for you. 
Gradle will do this again when your project is transfered to another workstation. So no more cursing about libraries that were not sent to you. 
Learning Java can still be done in Eclipse, or transfer to IntelliJ IDEA. AS is powered by IntelliJ, and has the same interface. IntelliJ and AS both get updates frequently, a lot more then what I saw with Eclipse.

Comment: Oh I see, its best I get AS then. So I will need to have a separate IDE for Android dev and Java dev now :/ Oh well! Thanks!

Comment: Not necessarily; see my comment above about the Andmore project at eclipse.org